# update same state twice in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

**How to update my state twice in same reducer**

> My state in redux store

```js
const initialState = {
 cart:[] as any ,
   Products:[
     {
       id: "1",
       title: "Realme 3 pro",
       image: {
         img1: "https://www.monotain.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/realme-5-pro.jpg",
         img2: "https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2019/smartphones/org/2019-05-20-product-7.jpg"
       },
       price: "10000",
       details: "Take photography a notch higher with the Realme 3 Pro as it comes with a 25 MP AI Selfie Camera and 16 MP + 5 MP Rear Camera with Sony IMX519 Sensor. The Qualcomm Snapdragon 710 AIE, multi-core AI Engine and Adreno 616 GPU redefine your smartphone experience.",
       seller: "Cloudtail India",
       quantity: 0
     }
   ],
```

> My reducer for updating state

```
case ADD_TO_CART :
  let num = parseInt(action.product.quantity) + 1
  console.log(num)
  if (state.cart.includes(action.product)) {
    alert("Please increase the product at cart page");
  } else {
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: state.cart.concat(action.product)    
    }
  }
```

Here I want to update the **product** to **cart state** as well as I want to increment the quantity which is updated to cart sametime

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the alert, try:

```
const updatedCart = {...cart}
updatedCart.find(i => i.id === action.product.id).quantity +=1
return {
      ...state,
      cart: updatedCart
}
```

Comment: I do not know how you have set up the rest of your redux, as you haven't mentioned it in the question, but you should be able to update state in your method by putting that code (or something similar) instead of the alert in the if statement.

Comment: My code which was written is updating the state and it is working perfectly fine ,what I want is to update the quantity after storing the product to cart. Please provide the code for this

Comment: The code you have written above just `alerts` the user. The code in this answer will find the product in the cart, increase the quantity, and update the cart state, as you asked.